# Vue2 dynamic input name

Tags: javascript, dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2

Using Vue2 I'm trying to create some input tags which have dynamic content. I have tried binding it to some function `:name="someFunction"` but that doesn't seem to work on this occasion. I need the name attribute to be in the format

`people[0]['name']`
`people[1]['name']`

With the number value being the key value of the loop over people. I usually create ajax/axios requests based on the stored model but on the occasion that method isn't possible.

Here is an example snippet of what I've got currently:

```js
new Vue({

  el : '#example', 
  
  data : { 
    
    people : [
       {
          name : 'Tom',
          age : 12
        },
        
        {
          name : 'Susan',
          age : 18
        },
    ]
    
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">

<div v-for="(person,key) in people">

  <input type="text" name="people[key]['name']" :value="person.name">
  
  <!-- The name should be dynamic people[0]['name'] -->
  <!-- and people[1]['name'] -->
</div>

</div>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-bind` (or its shorthand `:`) and make `name` into `:name`. This way, its value can be any JavaScript expression.

Example:

```
:name="'people[' + key + '][\'name\']'"
```

Notice the value of the attribute is actually the JavaScript expression:

```
       'people[' + key + '][\'name\']'
```

Which is a string concatenated with the `key` variable, concatenated with another string.

Demo below:

```js
new Vue({

  el : '#example', 
  
  data : { 
    
    people : [
       {
          name : 'Tom',
          age : 12
        },
        
        {
          name : 'Susan',
          age : 18
        },
    ]
    
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">

<div v-for="(person,key) in people">

  <input type="text" :name="'people[' + key + '][\'name\']'" :value="person.name">
  
  <!-- The name should be dynamic people[0]['name'] -->
  <!-- and people[1]['name'] -->
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you! Had forgotten you could do it that way!

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">

<div v-for="(person,index) in people" :key="index">

       <input type="text" :name="`people[${index}][${person.name}]`" :value="person.name">
  
  <!-- The name should be dynamic people[0]['name'] -->
  <!-- and people[1]['name'] -->
</div>

</div>
```

i think you must add binding key ":key="your_index"" and replace your parameter name key with index, so that the meaning is clearer